# spring security client_credentials grant_type - support for refresh token

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-zuul, spring-oauth2

Does `client_credentials` grant type support a refresh token scenario?

How should `access_token` expiry be handled when using `client_credentials` grant type?

I have an authorization service and secured services behind a proxy service (Zuul with `EnableOAuth2Sso`) which acts as a gateway for all requests coming from client application.

Here is the flow I have:

1. A proxy service (zuul) that accepts requests (rest api) from client application
2. Proxy service invokes Authorization Service api by posting `client_id`, `client_secret` and `grant_type` (`client_credentials`) and gets `access_token`, `refresh_token`, and expire time from response
3. Proxy Service routes the original request to protected services as per zuul route mapping.

This flow works fine but looking at the code in `ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider` I noticed that 'supportsRefresh' returns `false` and 'refreshToken' methods returns `null`. Does this mean that when the `access_token` expires any subsequent requests from client applications to the proxy service (zuul) will fail?

Answer (score 4):

`client_credentials` OAuth grant servers the need of machine-to-machine authentication, so there is no need to refresh the token.

As result, in Spring Security OAuth's [ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/grant/client/ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.java#L31-L38), `supportsRefresh` returns false and `refreshToken` methods returns null.

In fact, your authorization server and resource server are all in same place (which means the token generation is pretty cheap), quite much like our setup. I suggest you can just set a short lifespan (like 10 minutes) for access token, and treat them self-disposable, and get access token every time when you want to touch the secured resource.

Comment: thanks for the response. Few clarifications. 1) Resource Server and Auth Server may not be in same place 2) In our scenario its not the resource server thats getting the access_token. We have a gateway service (zuul) that is responsible for getting access_token from auth server and relay the same in the http headers to the resource server. My question is should our proxy server always get a new access_token for every request or is it possible to refresh only when it expires? I was hoping its later but looking at ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider class I see that its not supported.

Comment: Another option I am thinking is to have logic (filter) implemented in our Gateway service to check if the access_token in the context expired and then get new access_token using client credentials (client_id and client_secret).

Comment: @rgv, yes you should `AuthenticationFilter` to do these token related operations.