# Refresh token is not returned in oauth/token response of spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to create a Rest API with spring boot and spring security.
The below are the details of code changes I have made for getting authorization token:-

1] AuthorizationServerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {



    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password", "refresh_token" )
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read","write","trust")
                .secret("secret")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5000)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(6000).autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }
  @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

}
```

2] ResourceServerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ex/**").authenticated();
    }


}
```

3] MethodSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2SecurityConfiguration securityConfig;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

When I make the request through postman the following response is returned: -

Request URL:-

```
http://localhost:8090/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&username=sr7&password=aA$gm12
```

Response received: -

```
{
    "access_token": "6e55f38f-4aad-4e84-97d2-24b30d39bf5e",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 4999,
    "scope": "read write trust"
}
```

Kindly help me out to figure out what I am doing wrong here which is preventing me from getting refresh token along with respons.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try by using `grant_type=password` instead of client_credentials

Comment: Hi PrasannaI tried to enter grant type as password but it throwing error as invalid grant type

Comment: May i know the content-type u r using in request?? it must be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: The following is the url request I am passing through post man. "http://localhost:8090/oauth/token?username=sr7&password=aA$gm12&grant_type=password"

Comment: Am asking about content-type...header in postman request

Comment: ok content type: application/json and authorisation is Basic with my client name and secret key.                                                                                          Basic auth credentials:- username:my-trusted-client, password secret

Comment: change it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I changed but still the same result

Comment: What is the complete output?? i mean error_description??

Comment: "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad credentials"
}                                                                                                                                is the error mesage thrown

Comment: Note that you need to check if the password grant is suitable to your needs. Read more in my answer below. As for making the password grant work read more on the [official guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html). You could also use [JHipster](http://www.jhipster.tech/) Yeoman generator and generate an app with OAuth2 authentication and use it as a template for your solution. Disclosure: I'm not in any way related to the team behind JHipster. I just often use it to peek how things should be done in Spring/Angular

Answer (score 5):

[As per the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) you usually ("should not", using specification terminology) don't have refresh tokens in case of 'client credentials' grant type. Quoting [this answer by @chenrui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44510200/4494577):

> client_credentials OAuth grant servers the need of machine-to-machine authentication, so there is no need to refresh the token.
>
> As result, in Spring Security OAuth's `ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider`, `supportsRefresh` returns `false` and `refreshToken` methods returns `null`.

In 'client credentials'  bare client's credentials are used to obtain access tokens.

Recommended reading:

- [About OAuth2 grants](https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/)
- [Spring Security and OAuth2 official guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)
- [Spring Security and OAuth2 (Gigsterous blog)](https://gigsterous.github.io/engineering/2017/03/01/spring-boot-4.html)

Answer (score 0):

Besides using password grant type, try setting TokenServices support of refresh tokens on. Here is just an example, I don't know if the default token service will work in your case.

```
@Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        var tokenService = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenService.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        endpoints
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .tokenServices(tokenService)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
```